# Maximum Likelihood with dependent observations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, independence

In the context of a normally distributed dependent variable, the likelihood for a single observation is given as:

$L(y_i|x,β,σ2)=\displaystyle\cfrac{1}{√2πσ^2}e^{\displaystyle\cfrac{(y_i−x_iβ)}{2σ^2}}$

Then, given that all observations are independent, the likelihood for the whole sample is:

$L(y_i|x,β,σ2)= \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \displaystyle\cfrac{1}{√2πσ^2}e^{\displaystyle\cfrac{(y_i−x_iβ)}{2σ^2}}$

In the matrix form, the log likelihood would be:

$lnL = - {\displaystyle\cfrac{N}{2}}ln(2\pi) - {\displaystyle\cfrac{N}{2}}ln(σ^2)- {\displaystyle\cfrac{1}{2σ^2}}(y - X\beta)'(y - X\beta)$

My question is: how would you adjust both the likelihood and the log-likelihood formula to take into account the fact that observations are not independent? If you could explain the logic of how the formula is changed I would be immensely grateful!

Comment: Exactly what form would the lack of independence take?  Are you willing to assume it's multivariate normal, for instance, and willing to specify the covariance matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Whuber points out it depends on the assumption. So here is an example of some assumptions that could be made. First stack the individual equations

$$y_i = x_i^\top \beta + u_i$$

to get multivariate version

$$y = X\beta + u$$

then make some assumptions

$$\mathbb E[u] = 0$$
$$\mathbb Var(u) = \mathbb E[uu^\top] = \Omega $$
$$ det(\Omega) \not = 0$$
$$ rank(X) = K \ and \ X \ is\ fixed $$
$$u \sim Multivariate\ Normal$$

then the log likelihood can be written

$$\frac{1}{2} \log \det(\Omega^{-1}) - \frac{1}{2} (y - X\beta)^\top\Omega^{-1}(y - X\beta)$$

Assume that you want to estimate $\beta$ and that $\Omega$ is known, then maximizing the likelihood is the same as minimizing the sum of residuals weighted by the inverse of the variance

$$S(\beta) = (y - X\beta)^\top\Omega^{-1}(y - X\beta)$$

Of course, this gives rise to the Generalized Least Squares estimator, see [GLS-Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares), and the estimate is

$$\hat \beta_{GLS} = (X^\top \Omega^{-1} X)^{-1}X^\top \Omega^{-1}y.$$

$\Omega^{-1}$ is rarely known, but the GLS estimator is still theoretically important due to its efficiency properties.

If $\hat \Omega$ consistently estimates the covariance matrix, then the feasible GLS estimator is defined as

$$\hat \beta_{FGLS} = (X^\top \hat\Omega^{-1} X)^{-1}X^\top \hat \Omega^{-1}y$$

and if $\hat \beta_{OLS} := (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y,$ it is possible to get OLS residuals
$$\hat u = y - X \hat \beta_{OLS},$$ and then estimate $\Omega$ using these residuals. However, each term in the covariance matrix $\sigma_{ij}$ is only realized once in the residuals $\hat u_i \hat u_j,$ or, more importantly, this is not a consistent estimate of the variance, hence some structure must be imposed.

Amemiya (1985) *Advanced Econometrics*, page 185, discusses several standard approaches.

Other important sources imposing minimal assumptions on the covariance matrix are

White (1980) "A Heteroskedasticity-Consistent Covariance Matrix Estimator and a Direct Test for Heteroskedasticity" in *Econometrica*,

and

Newey, Whitney K; West, Kenneth D (1987). "A Simple, Positive Semi-definite, Heteroskedasticity and Autocorrelation Consistent Covariance Matrix". *Econometrica*.

For an explanation of implementation of these covariance estimators in R see

Zeileis, A. (2004). "Econometric Computing with HC and HAC Covariance Matrix Estimators". *Journal of Statistical Software*.

$$$$

Comment: thank you so much, that is what I was looking for! Amazing!